# How do I delete matching text with sed but keep the rest of the line?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a format string that is generally of the format:

```
PRODUCT_NAME-VERSION-OS(-INSTALLER)?.SUFFIX
```

I want to delete just the `VERSION` part of it. `VERSION` is defined as something matching: `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`. Therefore I want to do something like: `echo NAME | sed -i "\-/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/d` so that I get `PRODUCT_NAME-OS(-INSTALLER)?.SUFFIX`.

How do I do that?

E.g.

- Dropbox-1.0.0-win32-setup.exe -> Dropbox-win32-setup.exe
- gdrive-2.32.1-linux.deb              -> gdrive-linux.deb
- azure-92.0.3-mac-osx                -> azure-mac-osx

Comment: could you please post some real input data as well as the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` deletion operates over the matched line. So, in your exammple, you'd be deleting the entire line. You should head for *substitutions* instead. Take a look at the examples below:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(.*)/\1\2/'
    <<< "Dropbox-1.0.0-win32-setup.exe"
Dropbox-win32-setup.exe

$ sed -E 's/(.*)-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(.*)/\1\2/'
    <<< "gdrive-2.32.1-linux.deb"
gdrive-linux.deb

$ sed -E 's/(.*)-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(.*)/\1\2/'
    <<< "azure-92.0.3-mac-osx"
azure-mac-osx
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all from first `-` to second `-`

```
cat file
PRODUCT_NAME-VERSION-OS-INSTALLER.SUFFIX
PRODUCT_NAME-VERSION-OS.SUFFIX
Dropbox-1.0.0-win32-setup.exe
gdrive-2.32.1-linux.deb
azure-92.0.3-mac-osx
```

```
sed 's/-.*-/-/' file
PRODUCT_NAME-INSTALLER.SUFFIX
PRODUCT_NAME-OS.SUFFIX
Dropbox-setup.exe
gdrive-linux.deb
azure-osx
```